# Proving the Probability of an Event Through Bayes Theorem.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

The question goes as such: An event A can occur if only one of the mutually exclusive events B1, B2, or B3 occur. Show that

P(A) = P(B1)*P(A|B1)+P(B2)*(A|B2)+P(B3)*(A|B3)

my working out:

P[A|(B1 U B2 U B3)] = P[A INTERSECT (B1 U B2 U B3)] / P(B1 U B2 U B3)

Confused how to move on...

can someone please explain how Bayes Theorem works, and then how I should follow through this question.

Comment: One fact you need is basically the definition of conditional probability, that $\Pr(B_i)\Pr(A|B_i)=\Pr(A\cap B_i)$.

Comment: I wrote this above, didnt I? But only in terms of Pr(A|Bi) =...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Since the event $A$ requires any one of the events $B1, B2, B3$ to occur, we have :

$P\left((B1\cup B2\cup B3) ~|~ A\right) = 1$

---

$\dfrac{P((B1\cup B2\cup B3) ~\cap~ A)}{P(A)} = 1 \implies P(A) = P((B1\cup B2\cup B3) ~\cap~ A)  $

Comment: So basically it reads: what is the probability that B1/B2/B3 has occurred if A occurred, and because A must occur only with either B1 or B2 or B3, the P=1.... but i dont understand though how this follows through with the question.

Comment: Exactly ! I have updated the answer, see if you can simplify :)

Comment: well if P(A ∩ B) = P(B) *P(A|B) we can apply it to the above... because P(B1 U B2 U B3 ∩ A) is the same as P(A ∩ B) ... and then we see that Pr(Bi)*Pr(A|Bi)=Pr(A ∩ Bi) ... which can be re-written as the solution?

Comment: Use the fact that when events are mutually exclusive(disjoint), the proability of $B1 \cup B2 \cup B3 $ happening simply equals the sum of individual probabilities : $P(B1) + P(B2) + P(B3)$

Comment: basically the right hand side of the section you wrote above, is equal to the 'final answer' shown in the question??

Comment: yes! use both mutually exclusiveness and conditional probability

Comment: like this : $P(A) = P((B1\cup B2\cup B3) ~\cap~ A) =  P(B1 \cap A) + P(B2 \cap A) + P(B3 \cap A)$ you can simplify further and take it home :)

Answer (score 0):

Mutually exclusive events means that $P(B_i \cap B_j) = 0$ for any $i \ne j$, as such the partition of the event space (lets say $\Omega_A = B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3$) is complete and **any event $A$** (on this sub-event space) can be written as:

$A = A \cap \Omega_A = A \cap ( B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3)$ then by total probability formula one has:

$$P(A) = P(A \cap \Omega_A) = P(A \cap ( B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3))$$

since $B_i$'s are mutually exclusive

$$P(A) = P(A \cap B_1) + P(A \cap B_2) + P(A \cap B_3)$$

which by the conditnal probability formula gives:

$$P(A) = P(B_1)P(A | B_1) + P(B_2)P(A | B_2) + P(B_3)P(A | B_3)$$

it all depens on the fact that the $B_i$'s constitute a non-overlapping (mutually exclusive) partition of the (sub-)event space $\Omega_A$, as such requiring that the event $A$ occurs if only one of the mutually exclusive events $B_i$ occurs is equivalent to the joint event $A \cap \Omega_A$